# Remove duplicate records in sql table

Tags: sql

I have duplicate records in my table and want to delete them using Identity column values. I want columns "Fname" and "Lname" to uniquely identify every record. But there are duplicate Fname and Lname with different upload date. Below is the SQL query I designed to solve the problem but is will take Min(id) rather than Max(uploaddate). Please help fix this code.

```
Select Max(uploaddate),
   Min(id),
   Fname,
   Lname
From tbl
Group By Fname, Lname
```

Comment: You should make your sql code formatted as code by selecting the sql statement and pressing the { } button.

Comment: I thought I had an answer but I removed it as I wanted to confirm what the problem is.  From my understanding you want a query that will generate a unique set of records that uses the id of the last uploaded record?

Comment: @yaredmuluneh did you find my responde below useful?

Answer (score 1):

This may be helpful for you,

**CAUTION**

Since this is `DELETE`, before executing this, change it to `SELECT *` instead of `DELETE` and validate the output. If you are okay with result change it back to `DELETE`

```
DELETE FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE MY_TABLE.ROWID IN (
      SELECT ROWID
      FROM (
        SELECT MY_TABLE.ROWID
          , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FNAME, LNAME ORDER BY UPLOADDATE DESC, ID ASC) RNK
        FROM MY_TABLE
      ) TMP
      WHERE RNK = 2
    )
```

I'm not sure what is your database. I have tested this with `ORACLE`